# Angular filter object

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

What's the best way to filter a json feed by a schema Angular? The reason I want to do this is to reduce the amount of data stored in an html page using the Transfer State API.

Ideal world I would like to define an Interface, and have only those fields used. But Interfaces are only used on compile-time, not runtime.

So currently have resorted to using:

```
export const FieldWhitelist = {
  'slug': true,
  'title': true,
  'type': true,
};

get(url): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map(items => {
        if (typeof items === 'object') {
          Object.keys(items).forEach(field => {
            if (!FieldWhitelist[field]) {
              delete items[field];
            }
          });
        } else if (typeof items === 'array') {
          Object.keys(items).forEach(item => {
            Object.keys(items[item]).forEach(field => {
              if (!FieldWhitelist[field]) {
                delete items[item][field];
              }
            });
          });
        }
        return items;
      })
    );
}
```

This turns a json feed:

```
{
  'id': '12x324jh34',
  'metadata': 'sajhjksadhjkdsa'
  'slug': 'home',
  'title': 'Homepage',
  'type': 'page',
}
```

Into this:

```
{
  'slug': 'home',
  'title': 'Homepage',
  'type': 'page',
}
```

Is there a better way to recursively filter a json feed to match a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a class and map `items` in it, returning the class

```
const obj = {
  'id': '12x324jh34',
  'metadata': 'sajhjksadhjkdsa',
  'slug': 'home',
  'title': 'Homepage',
  'type': 'page',
}; 

class Data {
  slug: string;
  title: string;
  type: string;

  constructor({slug, title, type}: {slug: string, title: string, type: string}) {
    this.slug = slug;
    this.title = title;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

console.log(new Data(obj));
```

Also make sure to know what `items` is here, you shouldn't have need to check if it's an array or object IMHO, that should be clear from the returning part

```
 map(items => {
```

Comment: This is awesome, works perfectly. Think you have one error constructor({slug: string, title: string, type: string}) { should be constructor(data: {slug: string, title: string, type: string}) {

Comment: No @KimT , that’s valid object destructuring. It takes just the properties you want out of the object you pass to it. Look hat how I assign this.slug = slug,...  later.

Comment: ah strange, my typescript 2.7.2 compiler complains! another question, is it possible to shorthand if statements for setting variables? so you don't need to have one for every property? if (slug) { this. slug = slug; } without these you have lots of undefined properties

Comment: Sorry, how embarrassing.. I made a mistake here, edited the answer to correctly type the params, maybe it works then for you... You will have the property either way in your Data class, no matter if it's undefined or not. So I'd say you can just assign them - if they're undefined that doesn't make a difference

Comment: Or do you mean something like default parameters @KimT ?

Comment: what you've updated to makes sense! I was just thinking of a way to keep the model tidy, it's annoying to see lots of undefined fields :)

Comment: Sorry again, I didn't recognize my error even after you mentioned it... The only thing I could think of is to do `Object.keys(this).forEach(k => {
      if (! this[k]) delete this[k];
    });` after assigning all fields (after this.type = type; in above case) @KimT

Comment: yeah that's similar to my original approach, and feels hacky. I prefer your approach as it's specific and clear which fields are being used

Comment: Yeah, I’d don’t do that, even if you log data.foo, it will be undefined both if you deleted it and also if you didn’t. The only time you’ll notice that is when you log the whole object. @KimT

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to do this using a deserialize.ts helper class which stores properties using Reflect Metadata:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

const CUSTOM_PROPS = 'custom:properties';

export function Expose(target: any, key: string) {
  const properties = Reflect.getMetadata(CUSTOM_PROPS, target) || [];
  properties.push(key);
  Reflect.defineMetadata(CUSTOM_PROPS, properties, target);
}

export class Deserializable {
  deserialize(input: object): this {
    const properties = Reflect.getMetadata(CUSTOM_PROPS, this);
    properties.forEach(key => {
      this[key] = input[key];
    });
    return this;
  }
}
```

Usage for a model:

```
import { Expose, Deserializable } from './deserialize';

export class Brand extends Deserializable {
  @Expose name: string;
  @Expose image: string;
  @Expose link: string;
}
```